# Java: Google geocoding and places API status codes

Tags: java, google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get access to the status codes from each API.

Here's how I get a response for the Geocoding API:

```
GeocodingResult[] results = GeocodingApi.geocode(this.context, address).await();
```

Here's how I get a response for the Places API:

```
PlaceDetails results = PlacesApi.placeDetails(this.context, placeId).await();
```

I think these only return the `results` section of the Json response. I have been looking over the `OkHttpPendingResult.class` file, but haven't really seen any way of getting at the status code.

Comment: Which library are you getting GeocodingApi and PlacesApi from?

Comment: All of the google maps related APIs come bundled in the google-maps-services library. Here is a link to the github where all the java code is: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java

Comment: I think that library just throws an com.google.maps.errors.ApiResponseException from await() if the status is not OK, e.g. com.google.maps.errors.InvalidRequestException.  So you don't need to check the status code yourself.

Comment: The geocoding and places API have different usage limits for the free version, 2500 and 1000 respectively. I want my program to stop querying altogether when the places api's 1000 requests limit has been reached. That is why it is important for me to be able to handle the status codes. So in other words, when the limit has been reached, I want to stop making geocoding requests, and write the results I got to a file.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to catch com.google.maps.error.OverDailyLimitException then.  Are you not getting any exceptions?

Comment: Oh, looks like this might be https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/issues/156